# How can I prevent Outlook 2007 from sending e-mails to particular e-mail addresses?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, blocking, send-to

At work, there are a few Tony's in the global address book and my local cache within the Outlook 2007 client.

I never want e-mails to go to 2 of them. Is there a way to prevent e-mails from being sent to them by mistake?

Comment: Writing an add-on likely would be the simplest way, or modifying their contact card, so the email is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a macro with the code below. It creates a dialogue box to warn you if you are about to send an e-mail to someone on the exception list - you can then send or cancel.

Note that it needs to be added to **ThisOutlookSession** to work.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
   Select Case LCase(Item.To)
    Case Is <> "alias@domain.com", "alias2@domain3.com", "alias3@domain3.com"
        Item.Send
    Case Else
      Prompt$ = "Are you sure you want to send this to " & Item.To
       If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If

    End Select

End Sub
```